# Some Problems designing the GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

So, I've started designing a TicTacToe GUI in Java & I'm stuck.

Here's the code I'm working on

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class gameWindow {
int b;
JFrame frameX;
JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4;
JLabel[] labelX = new JLabel[10];
JTextField inputter;
JButton input;
JButton exit;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    gameWindow xyz = new gameWindow();
    xyz.go();
}

public void go() {
    frameX = new JFrame();
    //frameX.setResizable(false);
    LayoutManager lay1 = new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
    LayoutManager lay2 = new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
    LayoutManager lay3 = new BoxLayout(panel3, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
    panel1 = new JPanel(/*lay1*/);
    panel2 = new JPanel(/*lay2*/);
    panel3 = new JPanel(/*lay3*/);
    panel4 = new JPanel();
    //
    for (b=1; b<10; b++) {
        labelX[b] = new JLabel();
    }
    //
    inputter = new JTextField();
    input = new JButton();
    exit = new JButton();
    frameX.setSize(300,300);
    frameX.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frameX.setVisible(true);
    //
    for(b=1; b<10; b++) {
        labelX[b].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        labelX[b].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
        labelX[b].setText("X");
        if (b<4) {
            panel1.add(labelX[b]);
        } else if(b>3 && b<7) {
            panel2.add(labelX[b]);
        } else if(b>6) {
            panel3.add(labelX[b]);
        }
    }
    //
    inputter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    inputter.setText("Enter box number here");
    input.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    input.setText("Play");
    exit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    exit.setText("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(new forExit());
    panel4.add(inputter);
    panel4.add(input);
    panel4.add(exit);
    //Adding Panels to the frame
    frameX.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panel1);
    frameX.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel2);
    frameX.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel3);
    frameX.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel4);
}

class forExit implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
   }
 }
```

1) The first problem that I'm getting is that whenever I compile & run this, no component shows up on the JFrame. But then, if I maximize the frame all components appear. What's that?

2) If I uncomment the lay1, lay2 & lay3 in the JPanels declaration to use the JPanel's (Layout) constructor, I get the `BoxLayout can't be shared` error(runtime) & nothing appears on the frame. In this case, even maximizing doesn't helps.

What am I doing wrong & do you have a better way to create the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first problem, set the visibility status (`frameX.setVisible(true);`) **after** the addition of all the components inside the frame. In others words, put this line at the end of the `go` method.

Your problem is that the `JFrame` is displayed, and after that, you change his content. So the frame must be refreshed to be displayed with his new content. If you set the visibility status to `true` after adding the content, you will not get this problem.

Regarding your second problem, I never use the `BoxLayout`, but maybe you can have a look at [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) that explains how to use it. Otherwise, maybe you can consider using another layout?

Comment: Another problem is that once you setVisible you are absolutely not allowed to modify your frame's content in the thread you are using.  Technically, even for what you are doing you should be using invokeLater or something to get on the AWT thread before doing anything with the frame, but I've never seen code fail as long as you don't modify it after it's realized (after setVisible(true)), however Sun said failure was possible and that ALL swing updates must be on the awt thread.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, both of you.

But still, what was wrong with the BoxLayout?

Answer (score 0):

BoxLayout does cause these types of problems. You have to do this:

```
 panel1 = new JPanel();
 panel1.setLayout(lay1);
```

So the problem stems from the order in which you are doing things.

When you do this line:

```
  LayoutManager lay1 = new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
```

panel1 is not yet initialized so it is null. Unfortunately BoxLayout will complain about this. To solve the problem you need:

```
panel1 = new JPanel();
panel2 = new JPanel();
panel3 = new JPanel();

LayoutManager lay1 = new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
LayoutManager lay2 = new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
LayoutManager lay3 = new BoxLayout(panel3, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);

panel1.setLayout(lay1);
panel2.setLayout(lay2);
panel3.setLayout(lay3);
```

Comment: OK. See my edits above. That solves the problem and the program runs now.